# Rotate code on file in lateX document

Tags: rotating, code

I want to include a file with Haskell code to my LaTeX document.

Unfortunately, the code taking to much space, so I wanted to rotate it to have a `landscape` format, but somewhat, the code is almost disappearing.

Moreover the code should take about 3-4 pages, but only one shows up. 
What can I do?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[lstlang=haskell]{listings}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\parindent 0pt    

\begin{document}

\begin{rotate}{90}
\lstset{\tiny, commentstyle=\color{blue}, flexiblecolumns=true}
\lstinputlisting[language=Haskell, caption={Haskell Code}]{Code.hs}
\end{rotate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this code solution, I just downloaded some Haskell code from the libraries and saved it local in `Code.hs`.  I also removed everything except what is needed to solve your problem.

## First, use `lscape` not `rotating'

You can visit the documention for both at http://texdoc.net just type the name of the package and select the documentation.  The later package only works on one page, so your code is too long for it.

## Second, check the documentation

For the listings package the options are all keyvalues.  So you have to say `basicstyle=\tiny` and not just `\tiny`.

## Third, try `xcolor` not `colortbl`

When using colors an appropriate color package needs to be loaded.  Personally, I find that the package `xcolor` causes the least conflicts.

It now runs for me fine.  And, I have attached only the beginning of the output.

You now can build up your desired document a piece at a time.  Suggestion for debugging LaTeX problem.  Isolate the code and problem as I did and test it a piece at a time, with the documentation reviewed for correct syntax.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings,lscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\lstset{basicstyle=\tiny,  commentstyle=\color{blue},flexiblecolumns=true}%
\lstinputlisting[language=Haskell, caption={Haskell Code}]{Code.hs}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe, that this is a MWE. Please provide an example for the next time.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[lstlang=haskell]{listings}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\parindent 0pt    

\begin{document}

% \begin{rotate}{90}
\begin{landscape}
\lstset{\tiny, commentstyle=\color{blue}, flexiblecolumns=true}
\lstinputlisting[language=Haskell, caption={Haskell Code}]{Code.hs}
\end{landscape}
% \end{rotate}

\end{document}
```

I dont know the content of the codefile.